# How do I change the color of Dust 514 armor?

Tags: dust-514

I see a lot of people playing the game with armor and vehicles in custom color schemes. I want to know how to get colored armor. That's about it...

Comment: I've only played DUST once (and this was months ago), but would it happen to be just different pieces of armor?

Comment: I'm starting to think that, since I recently unlocked armor that was a different color. I keep seeing armor that isn't available from the shop though, so I still wonder. Perhaps some armor just isn't in the shop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what this is about now. Armor color can't be changed by the player.

Some armor that you unlock normally has a different color scheme. For example, Gallente assault armor has a black and white color scheme, Gallente logistics has gold on it, and all prototype armor has red "eyes".

More exotic colors like red and blue are special armors included in the special-offer packs from the Playstation Store. Since they aren't found outside of these packs, players will only see them after purchasing one of these packs or on other players who have. I learned this by asking someone who was wearing red armor.

---

tl;dr here: You can't.